# Runing rsync to new website gives connection refused

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync

We have an inhouse backup server (ubuntu) the inhouse server calls numerous remote servers using rsync. In order to set this up with a new website i need to ssh into the remote server and add my key to the authorized_keys file. Once i can login to the remote site via ssh from the backup server the rsync is then ran manually to build the structure (no reason for this but to confirm and to speed the backup up).

Today however I'm trying to add our newest website to the backup but the rsync command gives a 255 error and fails to connect due to a connection refused issue.

To confirm:

1. The remote server is lightsail with lampstack
2. We have multiple sites being backed up with lightsail and we use other servers too
3. Yes I can ssh into the remote site from on the backup server so key is correct and matches whats used in the rsync command
4. The rsync is generated and copied and pasted and has worked before
5. The .ssh folder on remote is 0700 and the authorised_keys is 600 and owner is bitnami
6. The pem file is in the correct folder /var/www/.ssh on backup server
7. The user I'm logged in as on the remote server when i run this is www-data (for ssh and rsync)

simplified rsyn command is:

```
rsync -rLDvvvcs -e "ssh -i /var/www/.ssh/LightsailKey.pem -p 22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress --exclude-from '/path/to/exclude.txt' --delete --backup --backup-dir=/deleted_files/project-name/ --chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fu=rw,Fgo=r bitnami@{ip}:/home/bitnami/live/my-website/htdocs/ /mnt/incs/project-name/htdocs
```

Error from running this is

```
ssh: connect to host {ip} port 22: Connection refused
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.2]
[Receiver] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=235): about to call exit(255)
```

What am i missing with this?

thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], [sf], or [su]. I'll add that "connection refused" with ssh is a pretty common question and you might have luck by searching first.

Comment: Hi @Kenster, I tend to find the community here at stackoverflow quite knoledgeable but will most likely try other sites if can't solve this. My issue is not that i can't connect with ssh its that rsync is not connecting via ssh

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was a typo in the ip field in the database.